# Hive - month and year from timestamp column

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, sql-timestamp

Hi I am trying to extract the month and year part of a timestamp column in hive using the below query

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(upd_gmt_ts,'yyyyMM')) from  abc.test;
```

The output looks like 2016-05-20 01:08:48

the desired output should be 201605

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: check this `select date_format(upd_gmt_ts,'yyyyMM') from  abc.test;`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'd prefer to use Hive [date_format()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) (as of Hive 1.2.0). It support Java [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns.

`date_format()` accepts `date/timestamp/string`. So your final query will be

```
select date_format(upd_gmt_ts,'yyyyMM') from abc.test;
```

**Edit:**

> `SimpleDateFormat` acceptable patterns examples.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 5):

Please use the following query

```
SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp()))*100 + MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **CONCAT and FROM_UNIXTIME** like below:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(1468215093)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1468215093))) AS YEAR_MONTH
```

In your query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(upd_gmt_ts)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(upd_gmt_ts))) AS YEAR_MONTH
FROM abc.test;
```

Comment: Thanks for the query..but this gave me semanticException. did not work as expected..

Comment: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:19 Wrong arguments 'upd_gmt_ts': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFFromUnixTime with (timestamp). Possible choices: _FUNC_(bigint)  _FUNC_(bigint, string)  _FUNC_(int)  _FUNC_(int, string)

Comment: is `upd_gmt_ts` your timestamp value?

Answer (score 1):

To see date in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format, you can use it as below:

```
select to_utc_timestamp(col_name, 'PST') * from table;
```